# Error when converting dynamic offset and datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetimeoffset

I have a dynamic parameter for offset and datetime.

And I have problem when converting the date.

```
Declare @STR NVARCHAR (MAX)
Declare @offset nvarchar = '+05:00'
Declare @paramrequest date = '2017-03-30'

SET @STR = 'select .... where '
+ CONVERT(DATE, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, + 'REQUESTDATETIME'), @offset )) + ' >=' + CAST(@paramrequest AS DATE);

EXECUTE (@STR)
```

When I run the script, it gets me this error. How to get fix this error?

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your string correctly. use `CONCAT` like this:

```
SET @STR = CONCAT('select .... where ',
  'CONVERT(DATE, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,', 
  'REQUESTDATETIME),''',
  @offset,''' )) >= ''', 
 CAST(@paramrequest AS DATE), '''')
```